# Proving that $\Vert T \Vert =\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq 1}\Vert T x \Vert$ defines a norm on $B(X,Y). $

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $B(X,Y)$ be the family of all bounded maps from $X$ to $Y,$ normed linear maps. Then, $\Vert \cdot \Vert,$ defined by $\Vert T \Vert =\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq 1}\Vert T x \Vert,$ for arbitrary $T\in B(X,Y), $ is a norm on $B(X,Y). $

we have for arbitrary $T\in B(X,Y), $
\begin{align} \Vert T \Vert =\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq 1}\Vert T x \Vert= \sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert = 1}\Vert T x \Vert=\sup\limits_{x\neq 0} \frac{\Vert T x \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert}.\end{align}

**MY TRIAL**

1.
\begin{align} \Vert T \Vert =0&\iff \sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq 1}\Vert T x \Vert =0\iff \Vert T x \Vert =0,\;\;\forall \,x\in X, \,T\in B(X,Y)\\& \iff T x=0,\;\;\forall \,x\in X, \,T\in B(X,Y) \\& \iff T =0,\;\;\forall \, \,T\in B(X,Y)\end{align}
2.
\begin{align} \Vert kT \Vert =& \sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq 1}\Vert k T x \Vert \\=& |k|\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq 1}\Vert  T x \Vert \\=& |k|\Vert T \Vert,\;\;\forall \,\,k\in K, \,T\in B(X,Y)\end{align}

3.
\begin{align} \Vert T+S \Vert =& \sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq 1}\Vert  T x + S x \Vert \\\leq &  \sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq 1}\left(\Vert  T x  \Vert + \Vert   S x \Vert \right) \\=&\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq 1}\Vert  T x  \Vert +\sup\limits_{\Vert x \Vert\leq 1} \Vert   S x \Vert \\=&\Vert T \Vert+\Vert S \Vert,\;\;\forall  \,T,S\in B(X,Y)\end{align}
Kindly help check if this is correct. If not, corrections and alternative proofs will be highly welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine except that you have to fill in some details on why $\sup\{\|Tx\|:\|x\|\leq 1\}$ implies $Tx=0$ for all $x$. You get $Tx=0$ for $\|x\|\leq 1$ and then you have to argue that if $x \neq 0$ then $\frac x {\|x\|}$ has norm $1$ so $T\frac x {\|x\|}=0$; finally, linearity of $T$ gives $\frac {Tx} {\|x\|}=0$, so $Tx=0$.

Comment: Please, how do I get an "if and only if" statement from this? From what you've stated, I think I can only get implication from this. Can you, please, help?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that $T=0$ implies $\|T\|=0$?